# How to get a user email from Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I'm confused here,

I'm trying to get user data using Facebook Api, I'm requesting email permission using `scope=email` like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_URI&scope=email
```

In Facebook access confirmation window I see that my application requests access to the email, but even after that when I do request to Graph Api it doesn't return the email (it does return all other fields)
If I do a request like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

it only returns id and name.

Comment: try it this way__https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all guys for your time. It started to work by itself after I deleted the app access from My account in Facebook and then tried to get access again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using c# sdk it's to easy with it. There are some examples in [this link](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FQL API for this:

**query:**

```
select contact_email from user where uid=me()
```

**Call:**

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+contact_email+from+user+where+uid%3Dme%28%29&access_token=[access_token]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have the permission of email or user have unchecked it while approving the request you raised from the URL : facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_URI&scope=email. You can check using https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=permissions&access_token=[TOKEN]. It should give you response notifying whether email permission is granted or not like below:

```
{
    "permissions":{
        "data": [
        {
            "permission": "user_friends",
            "status": "granted"
         },
         {
            "permission": "email",
            "status": "granted"
         },
         {
            "permission": "public_profile",
            "status": "granted"
         }
      ]
   },
   "id": "10207905751235096"
}
```

check facebook tool explorer for more: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is for an app, if so, I had the same problem until I published my app. Check the documentation to see if it applies to you:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/review-status/

After approved, the email and other sensitive info will show...